# Problemas con listas en java

Tags: java

estoy creando una aplicacion que coje las palabras de un texto y las almacena en un array, como no me funcionaba probé en almacenarlas en un vector y tampoco iba asique probé en las listas y sigue sin ir. Os dejo mi código aver si sabeis que es.

Pd: me sale null todo el rato si lo intento imprimir por consola.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Vector;


public class espanol_resumen extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public espanol_resumen() {
        initComponents();
        this.setSize(1000,1000);
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTextPane1 = new javax.swing.JTextPane();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        txt = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTextPane1);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        jButton1.setText("Procesar texto");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(jButton1);
        jButton1.setBounds(490, 320, 134, 29);

        jLabel1.setText("Introduce tu texto aquí y dale a procesar");
        getContentPane().add(jLabel1);
        jLabel1.setBounds(80, 10, 290, 20);

        txt.setColumns(1);
        txt.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 0, 14)); // NOI18N

        txt.setRows(1);

        txt.setTabSize(1);

        txt.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        jScrollPane2.setViewportView(txt);

        getContentPane().add(jScrollPane2);
        jScrollPane2.setBounds(30, 60, 380, 590);

        jLabel2.setText("NOTA el texto no puede tener más ");
        jLabel2.setToolTipText("");
        jLabel2.setAutoscrolls(true);
        getContentPane().add(jLabel2);
        jLabel2.setBounds(450, 40, 230, 50);

        jLabel3.setText("de 999.999.999 palabras. ");
        getContentPane().add(jLabel3);
        jLabel3.setBounds(450, 80, 210, 40);

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        String texto = txt.getText();
        String anadir = "";
        ArrayList <espanol_resumen> palabras=new ArrayList();

        for (int x = 1; x < texto.length(); x++) {
            if (texto.charAt(x) != ' ' || texto.charAt(x) != '.') {
                anadir += texto.charAt(x); 
            } else if (texto.charAt(x) == ' ' || texto.charAt(x) == '.') {
                palabras.add(x,anadir);
                anadir = "";
            }
        }
        for (int y = 0; y < palabras.length; y++) {
            System.out.println("");

        }
    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(espanol_resumen.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(espanol_resumen.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(espanol_resumen.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(espanol_resumen.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new espanol_resumen().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
    private javax.swing.JTextPane jTextPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea txt;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: `ArrayList <espanol_resumen> palabras` estas creando un ArrayList de Objetos `espanol_resumen' (que debería ser EspanolResumen) y luego le añades Strings. No tiene ningun sentido, es normal que no funcione.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No he entendido muy bien tu propósito pero antes de nada declara el ArrayList así:

```
List <String> palabras=new ArrayList<>();
```

Luego, para iterar haz algo así:

```
String texto = txt.getText();
...
String[] textoArr = texto.split(" ");
...
for (String s : textoArr) {
    palabras.add(s);
}
```

Y luego para imprimirlo igual:

```
for (String s : palabras) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

No sé si algo de esto te ayuda...

Comment: La primera parte si me funcionó sin error pero sigue sin imprimirse la lista